# Verification of Discrete metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

When we define a metric on $\mathbb{N}$ by $d(m,n)=|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}|$. I need to show this metric gives discrete topology on $\mathbb{N}$. For this i need to show singletons are open or in other words for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $r>0$ such that $B_{d}(n,r)=\{n\}$. My question is how to find such $r$ for any given $n\in \mathbb{N}$. For n=1, i am able to find $r=\frac{1}{4}$ but i am not able to generalise it. Please suggest me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you asked for **hint** this idea should work for you .

You know that $\frac{1}{x}$ is strictly decreasing on $(0,\infty)$.Also $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is strictly decreasing sequence.

Observe that for a fixed $n$ you have $d(n,n+1)\le d(n,m)$ for all $m\ne n$ and $m\in \mathbb N$. So you choose $r<d(n,n+1)$ and you are done.

Comment: When m>n i see that d(n,n+1)≤d(n,m) how to show it when m<n ?

Comment: Your sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ is decreasing so you have for $m<n$ $\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}\ge \frac{1}{n(n-1)}> \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=d(n,n+1)$

Comment: Yeah i got it thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $n<m<k,$ then $\frac{1}{k}<\frac{1}{m}<\frac{1}{n}$ and so the closest to $n$ should be $n\pm 1$. Try to show then $\left |\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}\right |=\left |\frac{m-n}{n\cdot m}\right |\geq \left |\frac{\pm 1}{n\cdot (n\pm 1)}\right |.$